# C# Check if certain screen is used

Tags: c#, windows, screen

I have three screens connected to my Computer, but only two of them are active.
 The other is turned off and dissconnected through the Windows-Display-Settings. Sometimes i will turn it on and use it.
I need a way to check if this third screen is turned on/the screen extends onto it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows forms, there is the Screen class, check if the device Name is listed in the `Screen.AllScreens` array.

docs: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2